# Creating an Internet Calling (SIP) account programmatically?

Tags: android, sip

Is it possible to create an Internet Calling account programmatically?

I want to be able to add my own SIP account to that list of long lasting accounts rather than using the SipProfile & SipManager classes for short lived sessions so that I can still receive VoIP calls once the app has closed.

I could launch the SipSettings intent, but it's not very user friendly, having logged in to my app once, they shouldn't have to enter yet more user details.